# No embedded path for shared library when linking with an absolute path

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

My development environment contains many copies of a shared library.  For development purposes I want to pass the absolute, or relative path to the shared library to GCC; so I do not have lots of -L entries making it easy to pick up the wrong version.

E.g., `gcc -o foobar foo.cpp /dependencies/fred/libbar.so`

However, I do not want the path /dependencies to be used as the lookup location for the shared library to be placed in the executable.  Is there an option so the command above is equivalent to the following?

`gcc -o foobar foo.cpp -L /dependencies/fred -l bar`

I am looking for something that is the opposite of *-rpath*, which includes a path.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an option so the command above is equivalent to

Yes: when linking `libbar.so` you should set its `SONAME`:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libbar.so bar.o -Wl,--soname=libbar.so
```

Once you've done so, `gcc -o foobar foo.cpp /dependencies/fred/libbar.so` will record the `SONAME` instead of the absolute path in the executable, and you will have achieved desired behavior.

You can examine the "what's recorded in the executable" with:
`readelf -d foobar | grep NEEDED`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot build the library, it is 3rd party.

Comment: @Marc In that case, you don't have another option -- you _must_ use the `-L/path -lbar` version.

Comment: @Marc Correction: `patchelf` to fix things post-link also works.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use [patchelf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/patchelf.1.html).

Find the paths using

```
readelf -d foobar
```

replace them with patchelf

```
patchelf --replace-needed /dependencies/fred/libbar.so libbar.so foobar
```

Then use

```
readelf -d foobar
```

to confirm that the path has been replaced.